# Cross platform non-browser development for tablet PCs?

Tags: android, ipad, ide, cross-platform, tablet

I have to develop an app for the Ipad. It has to be non-browser based. That's a  requirement and I can't change it.

I think it likely that the app would be useful on other tablet PC types and have a good chance of a second app which requires IPad and Android at a minimum; Windows and Linux would also be useful.

If it makes any differences these are "desktop" apps for tablet PCs and it is not envisaged that there will be any handphone development.

Is there a “Grand Unifying Theory” of cross-platform desktop app development? Is there a good IDE, preferably FOSS? I'd rather code C++ or Java and am less keen on Ruby or Python (through lack of experience) but would accept if there is no alternative.

I need a GUI builder, something like Borland Delphi or MSVC or the Eclipse Android plugin and  I need a way of executing different code on different platforms (#ifdef Android … etc)

Any ideas, or should I just go ahead and code the current project for Ipad only and stick to browser based HTML5 + CSS3 with Jquery/Ajax for cross platform apps (the problem being that some will need to execute native system calls, like en/de-crypting a file and at least one app has to work in “local mode” if there is so internet access, so I guess I would have to bundle a web server (Apache) if I go browser based (in order to serve the web pages), which would not be necessary with a “desktop app”.

Any recommended IDEs, Web sites? Books?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "grand unifying theory" is that core business logic should reside in the cloud; that allows your iOS and Android implementations to be just a thin GUI on top of this shared logic. Unfortunately, there isn't really a way to reuse the GUI, and even if you did, it would go against the intuition of users on one or both platforms, since  you wouldn't be using the paradigms of those specific platforms.

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) provides a way for implementing your core business logic in Java on top of Google's cloud computing infrastructure at reasonable costs (development is free, cost is proportionate to usage, and one can put caps on how much one is willing to pay). There is an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) plugin for developing App Engine applications. When developing for Android, you will similarly want to use Eclipse (there is a plugin specifically for Android development), although the Android SDK can be used just from the commandline (which is good for setting up a continuous build and test system).

For iOS, you will want to use the standard Xcode and the iOS SDK. Xcode is an IDE, but it is possible to build Xcode projects directly from the commandline using the `xcodebuild` command (also good for continuous building). The standard language for iOS applications is Objective-C.

Comment: I'll give you +1 on that, while disagreeing (in a non-agrumentative way). There are soem things that I didn't say because I didn't think them relevant. One is that internet acccess will be through very expesive sataellite link, so I want to D/L the data and process it locally - cloud is out, but you weren't to know that. I do, though, disagree with your statement on GUI; look at Java, Qt, etc which use native widgets ...   anyway, thanks very much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Even in the presence of cross-platform GUI toolkits your app will need to present itself quite differently on Android and iOS for users of those platforms to see it as "native." Both sets of users expect certain UI conventions and platform integration that are not easily abstracted in a general-purpose UI toolkit.

Comment: I'll give you +1 for taking the time to write. Can you explain to me what you mean - something other than widgets? What about Java, Qt, etc? If there is a problem ahead, I'd like to understand it, but still dont, despite waning from you an Michael; I suspect that I am missing something

Comment: @Mawg, even with Java (on the desktop), it takes two different implementations of the virtual machine to abstract away the platform differences (and even then, a Java app will not necessarily feel fully native without some platform-specific tweaking). However, iOS does not support VMs of any kind. You can only program it in Objective-C. Android does support C++ development (although Java is the standard way to write Android apps, unless you are implementing a game), but the APIs are completely different from those of iOS, so the only code that you could reuse directly is C or C++ model code.

Comment: ... the view would still have to be completely rewritten for both.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at jQuery Mobile. I used it to cross develop between Android and Playbook. I know that it also does iOS.

Maybe for you the downside is that you have to program in JavaScript.